# AtomicLong in Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I'm trying to use AtomicLong in Multi Threading Environment. My desired result is not working,

```
public class Account implements Runnable {

    private final AtomicLong amount = new AtomicLong(0);

    public Account(long difference) {
        amount.set(difference);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("The Balance is : " + amount);
    }
}
```

```
public class Examples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i -> service.submit(new Account(i)));
    }
}
```

I tried to use Read/Write Lock and block level synchronization but no luck. Could please someone spot where am doing mistake?

I output has to be starts from 0,1,2...99.

Comment: You want them printed in order? Execute them in a single thread (or with a *common* counter with access correctly synchronized).

Comment: Thank you Tom.  Let me try to share data and make it work in Multi Threading.

Comment: I'll note that if you use a single condition (lock for intrinsic locks) the performance will be poor if you have a large number of threads active because it'll wake up all of them for every number - O(n^2).

Comment: yeah i agree performance using intrinsic locks.

Comment: Also if you end up with a large amount of threads, then you need to rethink the code. The synchronization is the last of your problems

Answer (score 4):

There's no data shared between any of your threads... each creates its own `AtomicLong`, no sharing. Even if it was shared there would be no guarantee at all that the numbers will print in order. They would not even be a guarantee that all numbers are printed (some of them could be printed more than once).

If I change your code like this:

```
public static class Account implements Runnable {
    private static final AtomicLong amount = new AtomicLong(0);

    public Account(long difference) {
        amount.set(difference);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("The Balance is : " + amount);
    }
}
```

Here's an example of output I get:

```
The Balance is : 2
The Balance is : 2
The Balance is : 2
The Balance is : 4
The Balance is : 5
The Balance is : 6
The Balance is : 7
The Balance is : 8
The Balance is : 9
The Balance is : 9
```

The reason is that the following scenario is possible:

- main thread creates `Account(0)`. This writes `0` to the shared `AtomicLong`.,
- `Thread-0` starts up
- main thread creates `Account(1)`. This writes `1` to the shared `AtomicLong`.
- `Thread-0` prints the value, it's now `1`. In this case `0` will never be printed.

The only thing that `AtomicLong` does guarantee you is that all the writes to the value will always be visible by all threads making a read afterwards.

The properties of atomic variables are detailed in the javadoc (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)).

Comment: "It's even not guaranteed that all numbers will be printed (some might be printed twice)" I don't understand this statement: why not? (/Why?) An instance of the class is created for every i in the range.

Comment: I misread and thought the call to `set` and the call to `get` aren't atomic as they're in two separate methods (the constructor, and the `run` method). But in fact, all instances will be created in the main thread sequentially, only the reads occur in a multithreaded manner, so yes all of them will be printed with no order guarantee. Thanks, will fix :p

Comment: Thanks for your explanation @Dici and Andy

Comment: @AndyTurner ok, so I revert my reply to your comment but will make the answer clearer. What I meant is that **if** the data was shared, we would not have any guarantee that all numbers are printed it, and I just confirmed this. The reason is that such scenarii are possible: 1) main thread creates `Account(0)`, 2) `Thread-0` starts up 3) main thread creates `Account(1)`  (which writes `1` to the shared `AtomicLong`), 4) `Thread-0`  prints the value, it's now `1`. In this case `0` will never be printed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant something like that:

```
public class Account implements Runnable {

    private final static AtomicLong seq = new AtomicLong(0);
    private final long amount;

    public Account() {
        amount = seq.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("The Balance is : " + amount);
    }
}

public class Examples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i -> service.submit(new Account()));
    }
}
```

This will guarantee that each account will get a unique value of `amount`, but the values could be printed in different order.

Comment: correct, i tried with this approach also, got order was different.

Comment: @parrotjack Well if you really need the exact order to be preserved then there is no point in using multi-threading. What you want is serial execution - and that's guaranteed straightforwardly by single-threaded execution.